# Velocity Related To Gravitation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, orbital-motion

Which Equation is correct $v^2=\large{\frac{2GM}r}$ OR $v^2=\large{\frac{GM}r}$? I am getting confused here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are asking about a light sphere falling from infinity towards a heavy one.  Well, the potential energy at $r$ is

$$P = - \frac{GMm}{r}$$

And kinetic energy is

$$K = \frac{mv^2}{2}$$

Total energy is zero, so $P=-K$ or

$$v^2 = \frac{2GM}{r}$$